# ShellScript - help-me list files and subdirectorys

Tags: linux, file, list, shell

I'd like to know how to list a directory in this format.
normal list structure:

```
#find . -follow -type f | sed "s/.//"

/files/test1/test2/file1.txt
/files/test1/test2/file2.txt
/files/test1/test2/file3.txt
/files/test1/file1.txt
/files/test1/file2.txt
/files/test1/file3.txt
/files/file1.txt
/files/file2.txt
/files/file3.txt
/file1.txt
/file2.txt
/file3.txt
```

I would like
I would list as follows:

```
/files/test1/test2/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
/files/test1/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
/files/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

like this:

```
 ls -R1 | sed -e 's/://' -e 's/.//'
```

but would like the structure explained above!

Comment: look closely at how I wish! look at the first line of each!

Answer (score 3):

```
... | while read path; do 
    dir=$(dirname "$path")
    if [[ $dir = $prev ]]; then 
        echo $(basename "$path")
    else 
        echo $path
        prev=$dir
    fi
done
```

Comment: look at the model above!
want to list files, not directories!

Comment: Did you try it? How does it fail to produce your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting quiz !

Setup sample dirs and files

`mkdir -p files/test1/test2 && for P in . files files/test1 files/test1/test2; do touch "$P"/file{1,2,3}.txt; done`

As an one-liner, try

`find . -type d | sort -r | while read P; do printf "${P#.*}"/; ls -v | while read F; do echo ${F##*/}; done; done`

Output is like your request

```
/files/test1/test2/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

/files/test1/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

/files/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

/file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

A lot of fun to solve that.

Comment: did not work! he repeats the first 3 files. to test, change the names of files within the subdirectories!